# Heroku: bash: waitress-serve: command not found

Tags: python, heroku, waitress

I have a REST API exposed with Falcon and Waitress. It works fine in my local environment and want to publish it in Heroku.

To start the API, in my Procfile I have the following:

```
web: waitress-serve --port=$PORT app:api
```

And I can't see it correctly in the Free Dynos resources.

But when I deploy in Heroku, I get the following error message:

```
bash: waitress-serve: command not found
```

I'm using the following Buildpack: 
https://github.com/teamupstart/conda-buildpack

In my root folder, I have conda-requirements.txt with waitress==1.3.0

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

My fix for this was that I had not updated my `requirements.txt` file with my most recent installs. Do that, git push, and it might work.

I'll add also that my `Procfile` is this:

```
web: waitress-serve --port=$PORT --call myapp:create_app
```